# loading mask not tied to component, breaking on move of parent X, Y

Tags: javascript, extjs

**Description:**

I am using Sencha 4.1.1 and using a `grid`. I can replicate this problem by creating any panel and calling `setLoading(true)` on the panel.

**Problem:**

Sencha loads the mask separate from the component (footer). When the mask gets called Sencha finds the X and Y of the component and places the same on the mask. This why the mask appears to be over the grid. The problem is that when the X and Y change on the component, the mask isn't updated leaving part of the grid exposed and looking really ugly.

JsFiddle to show this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KG8yb/1/) - if you click on the "test" div, it will be removed and the error will be replicated.

**Question:**

I was wondering if anyone had come across a solution to this? Can I have the mask always tied to the X and Y of the component? Is this a broader issue with masks?

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue in 4.2. I use the following override in 4.2 to fix the issue (I haven't tested it in 4.1, but hopefully it'll work):

```
Ext.override(Ext.LoadMask, {
    sizeMask: function() {
        var me = this,
            target;

        if(me.rendered && (me.isVisible() || me.getMaskEl().isVisible())) {
            me.center();

            target = me.getMaskTarget();
            me.getMaskEl().show().setSize(target.getSize()).alignTo(target, 'tl-tl');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this is an awesome piece of code, but it doesn't take into account the fact that when the DOM changes and the parent component's X and Y changes, it doesn't update the loading mask.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I never hit that issue. This was specifically designed for handling dragging an `Ext.window.Window` around.